What is the purpose of Metadata Pointer Extension, given that Token Metadata means I can store metadata directly in the mint?
Reading How to use the Metadata Pointer extension  - and other sources - I am struggling to understand the purpose of the Metadata Pointer extension, given that the Token Metadata extension exists

With Token Metadata extension, I can put metadata directly into the mint. This is clear and very understandable.
When I read about Metadata Pointer, I read sentences like "The MetadataPointer extension now enables a Mint Account to specify the address of its corresponding Metadata Account.". I understand this sentence, but now I  don't need a corresponding metadata account, since we have Token Metadata extension.

What is the purpose of Metadata Pointer Extension, given that Token Metadata means I can store metadata directly in the mint?

There is the token metadata interface, which can be implemented by any program to function as a custom "metadata program".
The new Token Extensions program also implements this interface, allowing Mint Accounts to "point" to themself as the "metadata account".
The token metadata interface allows for the flexibility of custom metadata accounts, if for whatever reason a developer wants more control over the metadata accounts.

Thanks John! Knowing that mint account points to itself was the key to understanding this.
